# NodeJS console.log(anything) when the code stops working in terminal

Tags: node.js, terminal, out-of-memory

When the memory isn't enough, my code stops itself and gives a bunch of errors about 'out of memory'.
Is there any way to `console.log()` anything I want when my code stops working or i stop it by myself (ctrl+c)?

Everything goes up in the terminal.

Comment: Why don't you try to check the RSS usage, then call a gc or do something else to prevent from crushing?

Comment: I'm running so many terminals on a 600mb ram server. So when it crashes or stops working need to console.log()

Comment: Then you may check if rss has reached some limit and then `console.log`

Comment: How do I do that, new at NodeJs sorry

Comment: Please, look at my post below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like:

```
const os = require('os');

const THRESHOLD = 1000000 * 100; // 100 mb

// Check how much space left with a minute interval
setInterval(function () {
    if (os.freemem() - process.memoryUsage().rss < THRESHOLD) {
        console.log('We lack of memory!');
    }

}, 1000 * 60);
```

Comment: Please, pay attention that `process.memoryUsage()` returns an abject ([doc](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage))

Answer (score 1):

Well you can try increasing the memory limit of Node.js by passing:

```
// Increase max memory to 4GB.
$ node --max-old-space-size=4096 index.js
```

so it just doesn't crash.

Comment: My server has 600mb of ram.

Comment: @uhbc In that case this won't work. I'll leave this on in case a future reader with more RAM stumbles upon this.